# socket - broken pipe. Переполнение стека. Как лечить?

Tags: python, сокет

Вот ошибка:

> `File "library.zip/xmpp/transports.py", line 183, in send
>     self._send(raw_data)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
> error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Вопрос: как это лечить, не потеряв соединение и отослав raw_data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если получили broken pipe, то значит соединение уже разорвано.  Вы уже его потеряли. Поэтому, потерять его уже не получится (юмор).
Лучше поискать, почему сокет разрывается (проблемы со связью, нестабильный сервер, слишком много пишете, не проверяя код возврата от send, и так далее).